# Residence visa and Schengen visa overlap

Tags: schengen, eu, residency, 90-180-visa-rules

I am a US citizen who got a residence visa for Spain. The Spanish residence visa is valid for 3 month (June 1st to Sep 1st). Such a visa allows you to go to Spain and convert the visa into a residence permit valid for one year.

I went to Spain on 1st of June, stayed for 10 days and then instead of converting the visa into a residence permit I changed my mind about living in Spain and went back to US instead. I stayed in US for 10 days and then went to Germany on a Schengen visa (so, using just my Passport).

I know that on a Schengen visa you can stay 90 days in any 180-day period in Schengen countries, but does the count start from the day I entered Spain or Germany?

In other words, can I stay in Germany for 90 days or 90 days minus the 10 days I stayed in Spain?

Or maybe, maybe I am allowed to stay in Germany under the Spanish residence visa and when that residence visa expires I can stay for another 90 days under the Schengen visa?

Comment: By "went to Germany on a Schengen visa (so, using just my Passport)", do you mean that you showed your (irrelevant) Spanish national visa, or that you went to Germany _without any visa_?

Comment: @HenningMakholm by that I mean that I just showed my passport. I told them I am entering as a tourist in Germany. No mention of the Spanish visa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time spent *in Spain* authorized by a Spanish national long-stay (type D) visa or residence permit does not count for the 90/180 day clock. Time spent anywhere else in the Schengen area does.

Unless I'm misunderstanding your story, this means that your trip from Spain is excluded from the 90/180 day calculations, but the one to Germany is included.